# How the function in the Flask framework that can be executed once and before the web is rendered?

Tags: python, function, flask

I use the Flask to build the web application. I want the build model function that should be executed once and is ready before the web is rendered. Afterwards, it should not execute anymore and the model built is allowed me to use then. For my below code, it cannot achieve my purpose. Please help me.

```
import pathlib
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import main_classifier
import classify_header
import os
import logging
import SingleURLFeatureExtraction
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from process_url import process_url
from url_feature_model import build_model
from extract_msg import Message

app = Flask(__name__)

 

# Set up the logger
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

initialized = False

def build_and_initialize_model():
    global initialized
    if not initialized:
        # Perform model building and initialization tasks here
        global model
        model = build_model()
        print("Model built and initialized...")
        initialized = True

# Call the build_and_initialize_model() function immediately
build_and_initialize_model()    
        
        
@app.route('/')
def index():               
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def process_input():
    global model
    input_data = request.json['input']
    app.logger.info(f'Received input: {input_data}')
    features = SingleURLFeatureExtraction.addfeature(input_data)
    output = process_url(model, features)
    #output = main_classifier.process_data(input_data)
    app.logger.info(f'Response: {output}')
    return jsonify(output=output), 200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```